cs50 filter-more blur passes all test except 4x4 test
Sorry in advance. English is not my first language and this is my first question... Might not follow correct format.
I am trying to solve the CS50 filter-more problem with box blur method. I have to take a picture of height (height) and weight (width), and a RGB of this picture at every pixel is represented at image[height][width] for that height and width. I run the program. It blurs all correctly passing all tests but the 4x4 pixel test. I am missing something and i cant figure out what.
EDIT: I know there are other tests yet to be completed. The functions do not rely on each other. I am yet to start with the edges function.
Here is my code...
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int h = 3;
    int w = 3;

    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            copy[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
        {
            image_cord blur_cords[9];
            int toAddI = -1;
            int position = 0;
            // generate all possible co-ordinates
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                int toAddJ = -1;
                for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
                {
                    blur_cords[position].i_cord = i + toAddI;
                    blur_cords[position].j_cord = j + toAddJ;
                    toAddJ++;
                    position++;
                }
                toAddI++;
            }
            // get valid co-ordinates
            int valid_cord = 9;
            for (int m = 0; m < 9; m++)
            {
                if (blur_cords[m].i_cord < 0 || blur_cords[m].j_cord < 0 ||
                    blur_cords[m].i_cord > h-1  || blur_cords[m].j_cord > w -1 )
                {
                    blur_cords[m].i_cord = -1;
                    blur_cords[m].j_cord = -1;
                    valid_cord -= 1;
                }
            }
            float rgbtRed = 0.0;
            float rgbtGreen = 0.0;
            float rgbtBlue = 0.0;
            for (int sum_counter = 0; sum_counter < 9; sum_counter++)
            {
                if (blur_cords[sum_counter].i_cord != -1 && blur_cords[sum_counter].j_cord != -1)
                {
                    rgbtRed += copy[blur_cords[sum_counter].i_cord][blur_cords[sum_counter].j_cord].rgbtRed;
                    rgbtGreen += copy[blur_cords[sum_counter].i_cord][blur_cords[sum_counter].j_cord].rgbtGreen;
                    rgbtBlue += copy[blur_cords[sum_counter].i_cord][blur_cords[sum_counter].j_cord].rgbtBlue;
                }
            }
            RGBTRIPLE average;
            average.rgbtRed = round_up( rgbtRed / valid_cord);
            average.rgbtGreen = round_up( rgbtGreen / valid_cord);
            average.rgbtBlue = round_up( rgbtBlue / valid_cord);
            image[i][j] = average;
        }
    }
    return;
}


[Result of test]
Results on 4x4 image here

In the line for (int i = 0; i < h; i++), you are only looping 3 times, because h has the value 3. With a 4x4 image, this means that you will not process the 4th pixel in the row. This is why check50 reports that the 4th pixel has retained its original value 100 110 120 instead of being blurred to the value 110 125 135.

"It blurs all correctly passing all tests but the 4x4 pixel test." Looking at your first screenshot, that seems a bit off. There are other tests that fail as well. There is not only 1 4x4 test but multiple. And also some 3x3 test fails and other tests as well. You should run your program in a debugger and verify step by step that it does what you want for every pixel you want it to do.

@Andreas Wenzel , i don't understand your point. When i run that line of code, thats the I loop, i get values for i to be 0,1,2,3... these are 4 values

@ShakibKhan: Since h has the value 3, that line is equivalent to for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++), which means that i will have the values 0, 1 and 2 during the loop. It will have the value 3 only after the loop, so the loop iteration will not be executed with i having the value 3.

@Gerhardh I am yet to implement the last function. I was doing it from 1 to 4 and got stuck on function 3(blur). The 4th function(edges) doesn't need to be written for blur to work.

@ShakibKhan: Yes, you should not worry about the edges function until you have completed blur. Did your program pass the test in which check50 tested your program with a 3x3 image?

@AndreasWenzel WHy does h have a value of 3? It's a 4 by 4 pixel image...thats 0,0 0,1 0,2 0,3 for the first 4 pixels, no? Or am i missing something? Soryr if my question is dumb.

@AndreasWenzel Yes. I pass the 3x3. The only failure is 4x4

@ShakibKhan: h has the value 3 because you set it to 3 in the line int h = 3;. Are you maybe confusing the variables h and height?

@AndreasWenzel So sorry, My bad. I introduced that part of the code..so i can walk throught a debugger. It still doesn't work even after i remove it though. I'll do that now and send you the results

@AndreasWenzel I am so stuuupid!!! My code was correct all along. You were right, i intorduced those values to debug for 3x3 and never removed them. I had been working on this for hours and was extrememly tired. Went through it multiple times and never spotted it. Guess i needed a fresh pair of eyes. Thanks again!!!
